# While giving Calendar access from flutter app, not able to get refresh token. Require to sync calendar monthly once from backend

Tags: flutter

I am using google_sign_in library provided by flutter. Tried some other ways also but could not get any luck.

```
Future<String?> handleSignIn() async {
    try {
      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signInSilently() ?? await _googleSignIn.signIn();

      //safePrint('Sign In $googleUser');
      if (googleUser != null) {
       
        // safePrint('Sign In Successfully');
        // // You can access the user's information using googleUser object
        // print('User: ${googleUser.displayName}');
        // print('Email: ${googleUser.email}');
        // safePrint(googleUser);
        final auth.AuthClient? client = await _googleSignIn.authenticatedClient();

        assert(client != null, 'Authenticated client missing!');

        safePrint(' ID Token ======= ${client?.credentials.idToken}');
        safePrint(' Refresh Token ======= ${client?.credentials.refreshToken}');

        String googleToken = client!.credentials.accessToken.data;
        //_handleCalendar();
        return googleToken;
        //_handleCalendar();
        // ...
      } else {
        // Sign in was canceled by the user
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print('Sign in canceled');
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Error occurred during sign in
      print('Sign in error: $error');
    }
    return token;
  }
```

getting refresh token null however I am able to get the access token